# get_post_custom_values like spec

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I try to get all woocommerce products price with

```
get_post_custom_values('_sale_price');
```

but return always null, but if I use:

```
get_post_custom_values('_sale_price', 16);
```

Work fine (only product_id 16, off course).
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values
$post_id (optional)

How I can get all the '_sale_price' or all post_id???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved

```
 $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'product'
     //,'posts_per_page' => 99 
 );

 $loop = new WP_Query($args); 
 while($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();  
    $values = get_post_custom_values('_sale_price', $loop->post->ID);   
    echo "PROD: {$loop->post->ID} PRICE: {$values[0]}<br>"; 
 }
```